# https webhook not working - skypebot

Tags: node.js, botframework, skypedeveloper, skype-bots, microsoft-skype-bot

If i used ngrok webhook then getting call from skype bot to server but if i changed webhook to my actual https://example.com/skbotnode then its not working, even i am not getting any call from skype bot to my server.[image]

can any one help me regarding this issue?

I am using skype bot with nodejs.

Comment: using azure server

Comment: Not getting response on server after changing webhook from 'https://b5g5.ngrok.io/skbotnode' to 'https://example.com/skbotnode'

Comment: i have apache server running for other application. Is that causing a problem...???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried so many things and finally its working for me with virtual host.
With ProxyPass we can forward request coming from skype bot on default port to node server.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ProxyPass /bot http://localhost:8088
</VirtualHost>
```